# create global array (not associative array) with variable name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, global-variables

I have already read some questions and answers on SO that are related to what I'm asking, but I don't think they answer *exactly* my question.

I want to create a new global array if it doesn't exists with a variable name.

My Current Code is

```
function NewRoom(RoomID, UserID, Usrname)
{
    //Check if RoomID array is already declared or not and create new one if not
    //and add UserID and Usrname in it and then return it

    //My Current Code from a SO answer
    RoomID = ( typeof RoomID != 'undefined' && RoomID instanceof Array ) ? RoomID : [];
    RoomID[UserID] = Usrname;
    return RoomID;
}

var users = ['abc','def','ghi'];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    NewRoom('Room2', i, users[i]);
}

var users2 = ['jkl','mno','pqr'];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    NewRoom('Room3', i, users2[i]);
}

console.log(users);
console.log(users2);

My Console always show last inserted results like for above users and users2 it is

Object { 2="ghi"};
Object { 2="pqr"};
```

but this does not work and create new array everytime.

Comment: Can you provide us the tests you made please?

Comment: Well I have already put my code above what you need more? And result of above is it always create new array if this function NewRoom is called in a loop.

Comment: @JohnSmith *Every time* you describe a problem with "does not work" without further explanation, *something* is missing. Either you receive an error (and you should past *all* the output you obtain), or you have an unexpected output (and you *should* post both the output you get and what you expected).

Comment: Well @Bakuriu when I call console.log(RoomID) after the loop in which function is called it always give the last stored result in RoomID array. Let me update my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **NOT** want to create global variables. You can add the rooms as indices to an object, and read from the object to get all the users in the room.

If you want to create a 'global' array with the rooms, use the following:

```
(function () {
    var rooms = {};

    function setRoom(RoomID, UserID, Usrname) {
        if (typeof rooms[RoomID] === 'undefined') {
            rooms[RoomID] = {};
        }
        rooms[RoomID][UserID] = Usrname;
    }

    var users = ['abc','def','ghi'];
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        setRoom('Room2', i, users[i]);
    }

    var users2 = ['jkl','mno','pqr'];
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        setRoom('Room3', i, users2[i]);
    }

    console.log(rooms['Room2']);
    console.log(rooms['Room3']);
    console.log(rooms);
}) ();
```

Small tip: never pollute the global scope, except when some general variable SHOULD be global.

Comment: If declare it globaly like you said as var RoomID then it will be a permanent RoomID not will update it by adding data to it. I want to create a new array with whatever RoomID I provide.

Comment: OK, you want to be able to add new rooms. See my edit.

Comment: @Hiddle look I have updated my question for better understanding

Comment: Thanks Hidde. I now got it working. Hidde can you provide trick if I do not want to create associative array? Actually I didnt want to use associative array as i said i question

Comment: Why would you not want to create an associative array?

Comment: because I have to store a large data in array and if I use associative array then it will be long array so I wanted to be individual array for each different room

Comment: Let me be clear. It does not matter if you have one array containing *n* large arrays, or *n* large arrays in their own variable. Even better: always put the same kind of things in an array, so that you can reduce the amout of variable names you have.

Comment: There would be 1000 usersid in single room array so if number of rooms are 100 then it will be a big array. Do you have some trick for it?

Comment: It is not as if data becomes smaller when you put it in different arrays. So what if the array has 100000 items in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46348/discussion-between-john-smith-and-hidde)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
function NewArray (RoomId, UserId, UsrName){
  RoomId = RoomId || [];
  RoomId [UserId] = UsrName;
  return RoomId;
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My example is not creating new array if you are passing an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your array check is probably wrong. Use this instead:

```
RoomID = Object.prototype.toString.call(RoomID) === '[object Array]' ? RoomID : [];
```

Comment: No Use :( it is again creating New array with that RoomID I provide.

Comment: So, look at @JohnSmith comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
function NewRoom(RoomID, UserID, Usrname)
{
   if($.isArray(RoomID ))
   {
       RoomID[UserID] = Usrname;
       return RoomID;
   }
   else
   {
       RoomID=[];
       RoomID[UserID] = Usrname;
       return RoomID;
   }
```